# How to sort in non-increasing and lexicographical order in Python

Tags: python, sorting, lexicographic

How do you sort in non-increasing order a list of team names and scores, and secondly in lexicographical order? I have the following line of Python that I am trying to understand.

```
sigList.sort(key = lambda x : str(len(x)-1) + x[0], reverse= True)
```

From my understanding, this sorts in non-increasing order, but not in lexicographical order. I have a team name, and then the score for that team. I want it sorted by the highest score first, then by the team name. How do I do both?

Example:

```
BOB TEAM 9
DALE TEAM 7
KIM TEAM 3
```

The sort function in Python should automatically sort in lexicographical order, but I am only able to get my output sorted in non-increasing order.

Comment: Do you have list of strings or list of tuples you want to sort?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a tuple with the fields you want to sort by in that order.

To get the highest score first, convert it to a negative number.

```
sigList = ['BOB TEAM 9', 'KIM TEAM 3', 'DALE TEAM 7', 'FRED TEAM 3']
sigList.sort(key = lambda x: (-int(x.split()[-1]), x.split()[:-1]))
print(sigList) # ['BOB TEAM 9', 'DALE TEAM 7', 'FRED TEAM 3', 'KIM TEAM 3']
```